# Service Unavailable выдает на сайте через раз

Tags: php, веб-программирование, codeigniter

Проблема неуловимой ошибки, вроде бы все работает как нужно, но именно на одной странице вылетает эта ошибка с произвольной частотой. Подскажите каким образом можно ее классифицировать, ибо все методы что описаны в интернете уже не раз проштудировал и проблема опять таки остается актуальной..

Comment: Смотреть логи сервера и ошибки на стороне php скриптов.

Comment: Посмотрите текст ошибки из логов и тогда станет понятней)